# どんなリダイレクトツールを使っているか、を知りたい

Tags: line

公式LINEでたまに見る、こちらのツールは何を使っているかご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら教えていただきたいです。(お手数ですが、添付の画像をご参照ください)

<ツールの挙動>
・https://hoge.xyz/Vc など短縮URLになっている
・短縮URLをタップすると、添付画像の画面になる
・手順に従って操作すると、ブログサイトなどにリダイレクトされる

以上です。どうぞよろしくお願い致します。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2):

## 質問への回答

Javascriptが使われています。

## 補足

スクリーンショットに示されている内容は、リダイレクトツールの機能ではなく、iOSのWebViewの機能をユーザーに操作させるための指示です。

LINEやTwitterなどのネイティブアプリからURLを開いても直接リダイレクトできない場合にこの画面を表示して、ユーザーが指示通りにSafariなどのブラウザを起動してこのURLを開き直すことで、該当のブログサイトに（Javascriptで）リダイレクトされる、という流れです。

また、これは推測ですが、 `https://hoge.xyz/Vc`  のようなURLは、おそらく短縮URLではなく、リンク元をトラッキングするためのものだと思われます。

## 調べた方法

指定スクリーンショットに記載されているURLへ直接アクセスしたところ、 `sorry! under construction` と表示され、該当の挙動が確認できませんでした。
そこで、URLをGoogleで検索したところ、アクセス可能なパスを発見しました
（内容がスパムであるため、URL自体は記載しません）

そこで、該当URLを `cURL` し、内容を確認したところ、提示されたスクリーンショットと同様の画像（ `/A_files/pic.png` ）や、アクセスした端末に応じて `window.location.href` を書き換えるJavascriptが含まれていました。